# $ref undefined when using nextTick() - vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using an eventListener to get the `scrollHeight` of my 2 elements `h1` and `wrap`.

The problem I have is when the component mounts they show as `undefined` despite using `nextTick`. Only after the user resizes do they show the correct values.

How can I get the scrollHeight of `h1` and `wrap` on mount?

```
data() {
    return { 
      titleIsExpanded: true,
      shouldShowArrow: null,
    };
  },
async getWindowWidth() {
      await this.$nextTick();
      console.log(wrap)
      console.log(h1)
      const h1 = this.$refs.h1.scrollHeight;
      const wrap = this.$refs.wrap.scrollHeight;
  
      if(h1 > wrap) { 
        this.shouldShowArrow = true;
      } else {
        this.shouldShowArrow = false;
      }
    },
  },
  async mounted() {
    await this.$nextTick();
    this.getWindowWidth();
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => { this.getWindowWidth(); });
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.getWindowWidth() );
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have To wrap the 'getWindowWidth' function inside methods section.

```
data(){
 return{
  ....
 }
},
methods:{
  async getWindowWidth(){
   ...
  }
}
```